# C# Mouse Move shift

Tags: c#, mouseevent, remote-desktop

I am writing a program similar to TeamViewer.I transfer the image of the computer I connect to the form. When I reduce the form, the mouse cursor does not go where I want it. How can I solve this problem? The code is down.

```
private void pbResim_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = e.X;
    int y = e.Y;
    Socket soket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    soket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(karsiIP), 14533);
    byte[] gonderilcek = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x.ToString() + ":" + y.ToString() + "|MouseMove");
    soket.Send(gonderilcek);
    soket.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are not scaling the mouse position based on the scaled down version of the form. I'd also recommend you don't open/close sockets each time you get a mouse move event.